# how can i loop through this sample JSON array to get Issue-Name, Issue-Accuracy and Specialization-Name

Tags: java, json

I've seen the documents but none has given me the direct answer i need. I am trying to loop through a diagnosis array returned by apimedic in java. Below is what it looks like.

```
[

  {
    Issue: 
    {
      ID: 11,
      Name: "Flu",
      Accuracy: 90,
      Icd: "J10;J11",
      IcdName: "Influenza due to other identified influenza 
      virus;Influenza, 
      virus not identified",
      ProfName: "Influenza",
      Ranking: 1
    },
    Specialisation: 
    [
      {
       ID: 15,
       Name: "General practice",
       SpecialistID: 0
      },
      {
       ID: 19,
       Name: "Internal medicine",
       SpecialistID: 0
      }
    ]
  },
   {
     Issue: 
     {
       ID: 281,
       Name: "Food poisoning",
       Accuracy: 87.5,
       Icd: "A05;A02;A03;A04",
       IcdName: "Other bacterial foodborne intoxications, not elsewhere 
       classified;Other salmonella infections;Shigellosis; 
       intestinal infections",
       ProfName: "Foodborne illness",
       Ranking: 2
     },
      Specialisation: 
     [
       {
         ID: 15,
         Name: "General practice",
         SpecialistID: 0
       },
      {
       ID: 19,
       Name: "Internal medicine",
       SpecialistID: 0
      }
     ]
    },
     {
      Issue: 
     {
        ID: 376,
        Name: "Scarlet fever",
        Accuracy: 13.125,
        Icd: "A38",
        IcdName: "Scarlet fever",
        ProfName: "Scarlatina",
        Ranking: 3
     },
      Specialisation: 
    [
      {
        ID: 15,
        Name: "General practice",
        SpecialistID: 0
     },
     {
        ID: 23,
        Name: "Infectiology",
        SpecialistID: 0
     },
     {
        ID: 19,
        Name: "Internal medicine",
        SpecialistID: 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm trying to get the values for Issue-Name, Issue-Accuracy and Specialisation-Name. I have been able to get other things to work but this is really giving me a difficult time. Any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

Below is what i have tried:

```
try {

                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                    //get the conditions
                    for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = jsonObject.getString("Name");

                        Log.i("Issue: ", id);

                                //get the specializations inside every condition
                                JSONArray internalArray = new JSONArray(id);
                                for(int a=0; a<internalArray.length(); a++) {
                                    JSONObject jsonObjectInternal = internalArray.getJSONObject(a);
                                    String name = jsonObjectInternal.getString("Name");

                                    //display the specializations
                                    Log.i("Specialization", name);

                                    diagnosis.add(new DiagnosisModel("Headache", "009" , "General"));
                                }
                       // String name = jsonObject.getString("Name");

                        //possibleConditions.add(id);
                        Log.i("Line: ", " : " + i);
                }
```

Everything in the inner for-loop works fine and gives me the expected and desired result(SpecialisationName) but i can not get the values for the outer loop(IssueName, IssueAccuracy). I have tried everything. For the JSON library, this is what i imported: import

```
 org.json.JSONArray;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.JSONObject;
```

The Api i am trying to use is ApiMedic. Please have a look at it if that would help. 
      http://www.apimedic.com/

Comment: This is not JSON. And even if it was, it's not indented at all, making it very hard to understand its structure. And if you can't understand its structure, writing the code to extract information out of this structure is impossible. Post valid, indented JSON, post the code you tried, and tell which of the dozens of JSON parsers you use.

Comment: This indeed looks like JSON, but, as already mentioned by @JBNizet, it isn't. Keys are always double-quoted (like `"key":"value"`). That said, JSON is easily deserialized by a JSON deserializer like Jackson of Gson.

Comment: Any help with this would be really helpful i have been searching for a solution for this for days now. Been stuck since then.

Comment: @felix and yet, when you're being told to indent your JSON, to show what you tried, and to specify which JSON library you're using, you provide zero answer.

Comment: @JBNizet i am sorry for the late response, had no internet access for a while. I have tried to indent the JSON a lot better and have also added the code i have tried. i also stated the JSON library which is imported in the project. I am also new to android/java app development. Thanks very much.

Comment: hi @felix, `JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);` will return the `{"Issue": ..., "Specialization"}` right? you will need to get the issue object first before trying to retrieve the name - something like `jsonObject.getJSONObject("Issue")`. i'm not really sure what is the library you are using, i assume its [Stleary/JSON-Java](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java)...

Comment: @Bagus i have done that. It didn’t work. From all my readings JSON that starts with { are objects and JSON that starts with [ are arrays. That means that it returns arrays with inner objects. i need the value for issuename and issueAccuracy. Your method worked for retrieving only specialisation attributes. It didn’t work for Issue. Regarding the libraries i posted them above too. org.json.JSONArray;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.JSONObject;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about structure. Your pseudo-JSON starts with `[`, so it's an array.
Every element of that array start with `{`, so they're all objects.

Each object in this array has two attributes names `Issue` and `Specialisation`.

The value of `Issue` starts with `{`, so it's an object. And it has an attribute named `Name`, of type String. So you can get that attribute value using (this is pseudo-code, but you should be able to translate that to code)

```
rootArray.getObjectAtIndex[i].getObjectNamed("Issue").getStringNamed("Name")
```

Accuracy is another attribute of the issue object, of type number, so you can get it basically the same way:

```
rootArray.getObjectAtIndex[i].getObjectNamed("Issue").getNumberNamed("Accuracy")
```

Now, Specialisation's value starts with `[`, so it's an array. And every element it contains starts with `{`, so they're objects. Each of these objects has an attribute `Name`, of type String. So you get them using

```
rootArray.getObjectAtIndex[i].getObjectNamed("Specialisation").getObjectAtIndex(j).getStringNamed("Name")
```

Comment: Thank you so much @JBNizet. This worked very well.. Wow.

Comment: i wish i could vote. stackoverflow needs to allow people vote for helpful answers without the strict rules.

Comment: @felix you should at least mark the answer as accepted (by clicking the grey tick at the left of the answer). Voting will come very soon.

Comment: Just did. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @JBnizet. I finally figured it out with your advice. Below is the actual code that does exactly what i mean.

```
     try {
           //returns result of async task with api url
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
           //For getting the Name and Accuracy of the issue object
            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("Issue").toString();

                Log.i("IssueName: ",jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("Issue").getString("Name"));
                Log.i("IssueAccuracy", jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("Issue").getString("Accuracy"));

                //for getting the specialisation of the issue(inner specialisation array attributes)
                int arraylength = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("Specialisation").length();
                for (int j = 0; j < arraylength; j++) {
                    Log.i("Specialisation: ", jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("Specialisation").getJSONObject(j).getString("Name"));
                }
            }catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.i("MESSAGE 3: ", e.toString());
```